# Pygame groupcollide isn't working

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm creating a Space Invader clone in order to practice python and pygame programming. I'm using pygame.sprite.groupcollide in order to check for collisions between the player's bullets and the enemies, which is working fine. However, I have tried using that type of collision check to increase the player's score after a bullet destroys an enemy. So, I have created two score classes with their own images that change after a bullet hits an enemy in order to keep score. However, even though the two classes are almost identical, one's collision check works fine, while the other's doesn't. The most confusing fact is that if I change the order I add them into a group, or different groups, one will stop working and the other will get fixed. Here's the code:

```
...
_image_library = {}
def get_image (path):
    global _image_library
    image = _image_library.get (path)
    if image == None:
        canonicalized_path = path.replace ("/", os.sep).replace ("\\", os.sep)
        image = pygame.image.load (canonicalized_path)
        _image_library [path] = image
    return image
...
score_rect_1 = pygame.Rect (680,540,42,57)
score_rect_2 = pygame.Rect (740,540,42,57)
...    
class Score_cards_1 (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__ (self)
        self.images = []
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_0.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_1.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_2.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_3.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_4.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_5.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_6.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_7.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_8.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_9.1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.score = 0
        self.rect = score_rect_1

    def update (self):
        if pygame.sprite.groupcollide (player_bullet,flying_v,True,True):
            self.score += 1
        if self.score >= len (self.images):
            self.score = 0
        self.image = self.images [self.score]

class Score_cards_2 (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__ (self)
        self.images = []
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_0.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_2.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_3.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_4.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_5.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_6.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_7.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_8.png").convert_alpha())
        self.images.append (get_image ("number_9.png").convert_alpha())
        self.score = 0
        self.rect = score_rect_2

    def update (self):
        if pygame.sprite.groupcollide (player_bullet, flying_v,True,True):
            self.score += 1
        if self.score >= len (self.images):
            self.score = 0
        self.image = self.images [self.score]
...

global score_cards
score_cards = pygame.sprite.Group ()
score_cards.add (Score_cards_1())
score_cards.add (Score_cards_2())

...

while not done:

    ...
    score_cards.update ()
    ...
    score_cards.draw ()
    ...
```

I know that the score isn't being saved or anything, but I want to get the simple part to work first.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to add classes to a group, you have to create objects with those classes and then add them to the group

```
score_card1_object = Score_Cards_1()
score_card2_object = Score_Cards_2()
score_cards = pygame.sprite.Group()
score_cards.add(score_card_object1)
score_cards.add(score_card_object2)
```